# Laravel : How to handle Exception in View composer

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5.5

In my **laravel 5.5** project, view composers are used for passing data to the views.

In the **view composer**'s `constructor()` a `try catch` block is used to catch the exceptions and a **custom exception is rethrown** from the catch method.

In the default exception handler of the application, custom exception is  handled to display my custom error view.

**Problem :** The custom exception is not working properly when thrown from the view composer. Laravel's default exception error page is shown instead of my custom error page.

**ProductComponentComposer.php**

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;
use Exception;
use App\Exceptions\AppCustomException;

class ProductComponentComposer
{
    protected $products;

    /**
     * Create a new product partial composer.
     *
     * @param  ProductRepository  $productRepo
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepo)
    {
        try {
            $this->products = $productRepo->getProducts();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new AppCustomException("CustomError", 1001);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with(['productsCombo' => $this->products]);
    }
}
```

**Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof AppCustomException) {
            //custom error page when custom exception is thrown
            return response()->view('errors.app-custom-exception', compact('exception'));
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

**Note :** The custom exception is handled properly if thrown from the controller.

I also tried throwing the exception from the `compose()` method of the **ProductComponentComposer** instead of the `__constructor()`. But that also not working.

**How to fix this** to get my custom exception view if any exception is occured in the view composer?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: 1 of 2 scenario's probably, the issue was in `$productRepo` before injection, or the `compose` function is called after the view is about to render, so maybe try `View::creator()` instead

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The problem is occurring even with out the `$productRepo`. I have removed the injection for testing and the problem still exist. Also removed all code from the `__construct()` and throw the custom exception in the compose method that also not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where a custom exception was thrown within a method in my view composer class, yet `\ErrorException` is what I got displayed. 
There's a handler on a framework's level (`\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php:45`) I believe is causing this.

Fix I've applied:

**App\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AppCustomException ||
        $exception instanceof \ErrorException && 
        $exception->getPrevious() instanceof AppCustomException
    ) {
        //custom error page when custom exception is thrown
        return response()->view('errors.app-custom-exception', compact('exception'));
    }
    // default
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Make sure that what you're getting really is an instance of `\ErrorException`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will test it **later** and let you know the result.

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24658). Wasn't able to follow the thread.